# Filepath redirection

Tags: c, linux, bash, file-io, filesystems

Using Linux, I want to redirect access to files according to the app accessing them. For example:

App1: when trying to access "/foo/bar", access /foo1/bar1

App2: when trying to access "/foo/bar", access /foo2/bar2

The way I tough into doing this is by overwriting fopen and related functions using LD_PRELOAD.

My two questions:

1. Would be this strategy language independent?
   Edit: by language independent I mean it will not be affected by what language app1 and app2 are built.
2. There are better approaches, or maybe something already existing to achieve my goal?

Thanks

Edit: to simplify the question, think of /foo as symbolic link which resolves differently according to the app trying to access it.

Comment: How should than be language independent? You have to implement it in a specific language. Even if you completely replace a core library in your system with that modified code only those applications with share the feature that actually use the library.

Comment: @arkascha: I don't think there is a way to open files that doesn't use ``fopen`` at the end, so ``LD_PRELOAD``ing a replacement for ``fopen`` seems fine to me. I don't know what is meant by language-independent in this context, though.

Comment: @pmos indeed, only dynamical loading applications, but even that will be most. Still the question remains if there is no better approach. What about either a jailroot or a docker container?

Comment: @arkascha Thank's for answering guys. By language independent I mean with will not depend on what language app1 and app2 are built.

I will have to alter other functions as well, as unlink, for example.

Comment: @arkascha my purpose is to build a flexible package manager. The user should be allowed to alter the app directory wihtout caring to much on how the app access its files. Jailroot or docker container would bring undesired complexity and file duplication.

Comment: you will have much more file duplications when you overload the `fopen` call the way you proposed, I would expect. Since you have to provide _all_ files the application might require which can easily get tenth or hundreds on a typical system these days.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that replacing several significant functions of the C runtime library with versions that do something different and non-compliant brings undesirable complication and grave risk of unwanted side effects, not to mention undesirably tight coupling between components.

Comment: For Linux, you could consider writing a for-purpose FUSE file system that overlays the real filesystem, and `chroot()`ing to it.  This way you could implement something similar to your idea at the file system level, rather than by mucking with the standard library.  No unnecessary file duplication involved.  FUSE brings a certain amount of complexity, but what you ask is going to require that somewhere.

Comment: @JohnBollinger by using a FUSE, could I give different views of the FS according to the app trying to access it? In other words, my FUSE could access app pids?

Comment: @arkascha In my view, there woud by no much duplication. "/foo/bar" will not be realy there. "/foo1/bar1" and "/foo2/bar2" are also supposed to be a trick to have two different versions of the same app if the user desires so.

Comment: Yes, sure. But that means that for app2 you need to duplicate all files that app requires, I would expect. Since that one tries to access all files inside `/foo` but is redirected to `/foo1` for _all_ files it tries to access. But maybe I don't get the idea, sorry.

Comment: @arkascha Think of /foo as a symbolic link. Instead of a system-wide symbolic link, it should resolve different according to the app trying to access it.

In the case the user installs two versions of the same app, there would be the duplication. But my idea also is give to the user the flexibility to change where single-version apps should be stored.

Comment: Sorry, can't follow there. In my view an app has to access several files. Since `/foo` is an absolute path I have to assume that the fopen modification you propose alters the whole file tree the app can access. It cannot access any files outside of `/foo1` therefore. That means that _all_ files it has to access must be contained inside `/foo1`. That means you have to duplicate all dynamic libraries the app loads or might load. but as said: maybe I do not see the forest because of all the trees...

Comment: Ah, sorry, my fault. That is obviously nonsense what I wrote.

Comment: @arkascha it is a bit simpler than that. I just want to trick the app to think that "/foo1" is called "/foo", almost like a symbolic link. Each app would have a different "view" of the FS. The app can have access to other absolute paths normally, except for "/foo", which actually will not exist.

Comment: Sure, no need to repeat that for the 5th time. My mistake was that you do not modify the root itself, but a level above. So this will work unless the example `/foo` is `/usr` in reality.

Comment: Please consider limiting one question per posted question, instead of two questions in one question post. This makes stackoverflow's searching and scoring work better (imagine if two people each answer one of the questions -- which answer do you mark as correct?)

Comment: @pmos "I don't think there is a way to open files that doesn't use `fopen` at the end"  How about `open()`, `creat()`, and (perhaps) the 64-bit variations such as `fopen64()`.  And what are you going to do if the application tries to use `stat()` or `lstat()` against the file, or if the file descriptor is passed from another process?  Using LD_PRELOAD this way is fraught with peril.

Comment: @AndrewHenle good point, i hadn't think of that. I guess it would be a price to pay in order to provide different filesystem views for each app. I know it has its hazards, but I won't use this in a production environment, at least not initially.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Fair enough, but either way the number of these kinds of syscalls is limited. I've known plenty of programs that use preloading in this way to achieve other goals and they work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For my particular case, the best option is to use LD_PRELOAD to overwrite open, open64, etc.

If you are facing a similar problem, check also chroot, jail root and docker container.